# Verifying an equation involving entropy and mutual information

Tags: statistics, information-theory

I would like to show the following:

> Consider a joint distribution of $X,Y$ with density $p(x,y)$. For arbitrary functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ we have:
>
> $$ H(X) + H(Y-f(X)) = H(Y) + H(X-g(Y)) - I(X-g(Y),Y) + I(Y-f(X),X)$$
>
> where $H$ is the entropy and $I$ is the mutual information.

"Expanding" the right hand side, I got

$$H(Y) + H(X-g(Y)) - H(X-g(Y)) - H(Y) + H(X-g(Y),Y) + H(Y-f(X)) + H(X) - H(Y-f(X),X)$$

which simplies to

$$H(X) + H(Y-f(X)) + \color{red}{H(X-g(Y))+H(Y|X-g(Y)) - H(Y-f(X))-H(X|Y-f(X))}$$

What properties should I use to get rid of the red part?

Comment: In general, it is best to condition on a single random variable, not a function of several random variables.  In particular, $H(X-g(Y)|Y)$ is more workable than $H(Y|X-g(Y))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$H(Y) + H(X-g(Y)) - H(X-g(Y)) - H(Y) + H(X-g(Y),Y) + H(Y-f(X)) + H(X) - H(Y-f(X),X)$$

The first 4 terms cancel each other out and it becomes:

$$H(Y-f(X)) + H(X) + H(X-g(Y),Y) - H(Y-f(X),X)$$

However,

\begin{align}
H(X-g(Y),Y)&=H(Y)+H(X-g(Y)|Y)\\
&=H(Y)+H(X)
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
H(Y-f(X),X)&=H(X)+H(Y-f(X)|X)\\
&=H(X)+H(Y)
\end{align}

Hence,

$$H(X-g(Y),Y) - H(Y-f(X),X)=H(Y)+H(X)-\left(H(X)+H(Y)\right)=0$$

and it becomes

$$H(Y-f(X)) + H(X)$$

which is the LHS.

Comment: Why is $H(X-g(Y)|Y) = H(X)$?

Comment: $H(X-g(Y)|Y)=H(X-Y|Y)=H(X)$ since $g(Y)$ fully depends on $Y$ and when $Y$ is given then it is not random anymore and all randomness comes from $X$.

Comment: That's why I'm not used to all this "randomness" in probability theory. But the answer looks valid :)

Comment: When Y is given, it is not a random variable and should be treated like a deterministic constant $c$. The PDF of $X\mp c$ is the same as the pdf of $X$. (Proof: You can imagine a delta for the pdf of $c$ and when it is convolved with the pdf of $X$ it will remain unchanged.) Therefore $H(X-g(Y)|Y)=H(X\mp c)=H(X)$